# Supporting AOL login with Google Identity Toolkit (xrds)

Tags: google-identity-toolkit, xrds

I'm working on getting Google Identity Toolkit set up, and according to the [AOL instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/v2/devconsole#supporting-federated-login-with-hotmail), you have to place a xrds document in the site's root to avoid warnings on the user's end. I'm a little confused as to how this works. Do I simply create xrds.xml with the relevant content and place it in the root directory, or does the file need to be referenced in the site's page headers as well? Is this still applicable to Identity Toolkit V3?

Answer (score 0):

Google Identity Toolkit V3 is the recommended version and the XRDS file is needed as well.

The XRDS file could be of any name on your site, and your site could
return the file name through either

1) an HTML document with a  element that includes a 
element with http-equiv attribute, X-XRDS-Location,

or

2) HTTP response-headers that include an X-XRDS-Location response-header

An example of #2 is your server returns http response with header

```
X-XRDS-Location: https://your-web-site.com/yadis.html
```

where the content of the yadis.html looks like

```
<xrds:XRDS><XRD>
  <Service>
    <Type>http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/return_to</Type>
    <URI>https://your-web-site.com/gitkit</URI>
  </Service>
</XRD></xrds:XRDS>
```